# grouping a column based in distinct id's

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many

I have three tables college_details, college_courses, course of which college_courses is an intermediate table for many to many relation ships between college_details and course.

college_details

```
+------------+--------------+
| college_id | college_name |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | abc, Nagpur  |
|          2 | xyz, Nagpur  |
|          3 | mnop, Nagpur |
+------------+--------------+
```

college_courses

```
+------------+--------------+
| college_id | course_id    |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 |            1 |
|          1 |            5 |
|          2 |            3 |
|          3 |            5 |
+---------------------------+
```

course

```
+----------+-------------+
|course_id | course_name |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 | B.E         |
|        2 | M.E         |
|        3 | M.Tech      |
|        4 | B.Tech      |
|        5 | M.B.A       |
+----------+-------------+


SELECT cd.college_id
     , cd.college_name
     , c.course_name 
  FROM college_details AS cd 
  LEFT 
  JOIN college_courses AS cc 
    ON cc.college_id = cd.college_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN course AS c 
    ON  cc.course_id =  c.course_id
```

From the above query I get the following table.

```
+------------+---------------+-------------+
| college_id | college_name | course_name |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
|          1 | abc, college | be          |
|          1 | abc, college | mba         |
|          2 | xyz, college | me          |
|          3 | mnop, college | btech       |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

query -> `"SELECT cd.college_id,cd.college_name,GROUP_CONCAT(c.course_name) FROM college_details AS cd LEFT JOIN college_courses AS cc ON cc.college_id = cd.college_id  LEFT JOIN course AS c ON  cc.college_id =  c.course_id ";`

And from above query I get the following table.

```
+------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
| college_id | college_name | GROUP_CONCAT(c.course_name) |
+------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
|          1 | abc, college | be,be,me,btech              |
+------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
```

But what I want is the following table.

```
+------------+---------------+-------------+
| college_id | college_name  | course_name |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
|          1 | abc, college  | be,mba      |
|          2 | xyz, college  | me          |
|          3 | mnop, college | btech       |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I just can't think why you'd want this result in this way

Comment: I want this for displaying college name with there particular courses to the end user

Comment: The end user uses the MySQL CLI?

Comment: no , i will display end users using php mysql

Comment: So get rid of all that GROUP_CONCAT stuff. Display issues should be handled in application code

Comment: so u mean there is no query in mysql for that thing

Comment: I'm just saying it's not the way I'd do it!

Comment: ok, i m open to other solutions also if this cant be done in mysql

Comment: Obviously you're missing a GROUP BY clause- but it's just not how I'd do it. Instead I'd use a loop to parse the array into whatever display made the most sense for the end user

Comment: I thought of group by earlier but didn't quit get how would i use that

Comment: It's very easy. You just GROUP BY all the columns in the SELECT that are NOT being aggregated.

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Comment: just curious , why would you prefer to do that in application code

Comment: Because it's so much more scalable and flexible